# Sample activity group code

Tags: android, activitygroup

Can someone give me some sample code using activity group?

There are buttons in my application and I want to apply activity to those buttons.  Currently I'm using setVisibility(), but I've been advised that activity group would be a better choice.

Comment: Please refer this link: [**Go Here**](http://gamma-point.com/content/android-how-have-multiple-activities-under-single-tab-tabactivity)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `ActivityGroup` [sample project](http://richipal.com/post/2624844577). There is a link on the page to download the actual project.