# ListView on TabActivity, hide the Tabs

Tags: android, listview, layout, hide, tabactivity

I have one listview on a Tab. when click on a item on that listview, go to another listview. The problem is: That second listview hide the TabMenu on the top. Someone ?
Thanks.

The code of the second listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/list"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you start an Activity from your current Activity. Since you are not calling a Tab Activity but instead you just call a Activity, your tabs gets removed. It doesn't mean that your tabs are hidden, but rather you are not in your Tab Activity.

Android has a special implementation called **ActivityGroup**. These links will help you to get started.

[Sample activity group code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5402119/603744)

http://www.gamma-point.com/content/android-how-have-multiple-activities-under-single-tab-tabactivity

Comment: Thanks Andro. Im going to see that documentation. :)

Comment: ActivityGroup is deprecated. Im going to try undestand the fragments.

Comment: Done Andro, for your support. ;)